# Adding a static file directory to override CSS in Django

Tags: css, django, static, pinax

I'm trying to figure out why I can't override `base.css` in Django.

In `settings.py` I have:

```
STATIC_URL = "/site_media/static/"
```

And in `site_base.html`:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ STATIC_URL }}pinax/css/base.css" />
```

And I have customized the file located in `/site_media/static/pinax/css/base.css`. But instead of reading the file from here, it is reading it from my `python/site-packages/pinax` directory still. And in the same `site_base.html` file I am able to override an image which is in the `/site_media_static/pinax/images/` folder, which seems odd that I can overwrite the image but not the CSS file.

Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `STATIC_URL` is the URL static files are served from, not the directory where they are stored.

You need to add the directory containing your static files to `STATICFILES_DIRS` or put your static files in an app's `static` subdir.

See the docs for the [Django staticfiles app](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/ref/contrib/staticfiles/).

Comment: I am using `collectstatic` and was wondering why it wasn't collecting my over-ridden base.css for the django admin. The [staticfiles app docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/contrib/staticfiles/#collectstatic) state: "the file that is first found in one of the specified locations will be used".  So I moved `'mysite'` in the `INSTALLED_APPS` setting to the first position. It now copies `mysite/static/admin/css/base.css` instead of `python/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/css/base.css`.

Answer (score 0):

`STATIC_ROOT` (which is referenced by `STATIC_URL`) should not be modified manually, it's being populated by `collectstatic` command from ann apps static dirs and `STATICFILES_DIRS`. In Django's dev server there is also a helper which allows accessing static file directly from the source, that allows easier debugging of JS and CSS.

In your case you can try putting updated file somewhere inside `STATICFILES_DIRS`. Also, take a look at [`STATICFILES_FINDERS`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/ref/contrib/staticfiles/) which can change ordering for static files finders to set which one will have the priority.